# .htaccess Error documents

Tags: .htaccess, wampserver, errordocument

I got a little problem.

I would like to add my own custom error pages to my system.
Formerly I have always succeeded in this.
But now I cannot. And I do not understand why.

This is the code that I got working with one of my websites.

```
errordocument 404 http://www.clientdomain.com/404/20/
```

But the following code actually the same (I think)
And it does not work.

```
########=======================================================
######## ERROR DOCUMENTS
########=======================================================
errordocument 403   ?pagenotfound=403
errordocument 404   ?pagenotfound=404
errordocument 500   ?pagenotfound=500
########=======================================================
```

All it does is showing : **?pagenotfound=404**

When a page has not been found.

When adding a slash forward:

```
########=======================================================
######## ERROR DOCUMENTS
########=======================================================
errordocument 403   /?pagenotfound=403
errordocument 404   /?pagenotfound=404
errordocument 500   /?pagenotfound=500
########=======================================================
```

It gives the wamp server main page when a page has not been found.

Could anybody see what I have done wrong??

Comment: What is the entire path to the file you want to display on error ?

Comment: What's wrong with `errordocument 404   /?pagenotfound=404`

Comment: @Justin Lurman well at this moment it is (localhost) http://domain1.nl/psystem2014/?